# What is a common practice for storing players/user ranking?

Tags: sql, database

There are lots of apps where user is getting some points now and then and has his overall ranking (comparing his points with other users).

So let's say there is a table that contains:

```
some_action_id, points_for_action
```

I am wondering if whole ranking is run based on this simple table and displayed with some groupbys and rank functions?

This seems most reasonable for me, but then how eg *'user higest ranking'* is stored?

Comment: There should be player id in that table too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach here, which you might have an interest in taking, would actually be to maintain *two* tables related to user points.  One table would store each transaction in a separate record.  As to why you might need this, if you ever had the need to go back in a user's history and see what happened, a transaction table would be crucial.  As an example, consider the Stack Overflow site, which displays both the user's total score, as well as giving the option to see the full history.

The *second* table would just maintain a single record for each user.  This record would contain grand totals, such as the total point score.  This table would be updated via a *trigger* from the first transaction table.  That is, whenever there is a user activity resulting in a change in points, the trigger would update the grand total table.  The advantage of this approach is that the totals are instantly available.  On the other hand, just maintaining a single table with transactions would pose a potential problem for obtaining aggregates.  In that case, we would have to do a costly database operation each time we wanted to see a total, and the problem would grow worse as the number of users increase and as a given user's tenure on the site increases.

Putting this all together, the table definitions might look something like this:

```
table transactions: (user_id, some_action_id, points_for_action);
table totals:       (user_id, points_total);
```

The first table would update the second table via a trigger.

Comment: Thanks! I think this is exactly the answer I was looking for. If I could get info about user_id through 'some_action_id' should I also store it in transactions table? And what would be the best approach to store user highest ranking then? Add 'ranking' column in 'totals' and then every 'totals' update would trigger new 'user_ranking_history' table ?

Comment: @Sygol I don't follow your comment, but if you can explain more I'm happy to edit my answer.

Comment: Forget question about 'user_id'. But let's say that my current ranking is 15, then week later I am 17th, but in my 'info_account' I would like to see my current ranking (17) but also my highest ranking (15). How to go about that? Create 'user_ranking_history' table and add 'current_ranking' column in 'totals' and then every 'totals' change would update 'user_ranking_history' table ?

Comment: Well, continuing with Stack Overflow as an example, SO maintains weekly, quarterly, annual, and all-time rankings.  So, you could have a separate table for each.  If you require something other than this, then you might have to hit the transaction table with an ugly (and possibly non performant query).

Comment: And then annual_ranking_table would be something like: 'user_id', 'year', 'total'? Then I would get a 'total' from transactions in particular year?

Comment: Yes, and the trigger would only update the total record for the year in which the points were changed.

Answer (score 0):

You want to have a Column on the user, where you have the calculated value.

That Column you then calculate (or just add the newly appointed points) when new points are awarded.

Comment: _Column_, not field.